# Google Cloud Labels Acces by api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tags, label

How do I get the labels for all the resources in GCP with the use of api? Is there any specific api to access or view all the labels of all resources for a given project?

Answer (score 1):

You can view labels for resources by using the Cloud Console, the gcloud tool, or the Compute Engine API. To view labels for forwarding rules, use the gcloud tool or the Compute Engine API.

To retrieve labels with the use of api, make a **GET** request to the following resource:

1. For VM instances, use the **instances.setLabels()** method.
2. For snapshots, use the **snapshots.setLabels()** method.
3. For images, use the **images.setLabels()** method.
4. For disks, use the **disks.setLabels()** method.
5. For forwarding rules, use the beta **forwardingRules.setLabels()** method.
6. For regional static external IP addresses, use the beta **addresses.setLabels()** method.
7. For global static external IP addresses, use the beta **globalAddresses.setLabels()** method.
8. For VPN tunnels, use the beta **vpnTunnels.setLabels()** method.

For example, the following snippet makes a GET request to retrieve labels for a VM instance:

```
GET https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/ZONE/instances/VM_NAME
```

Refer to the document on [Creating and Managing Labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources#api_2).